# New template not showing up in Template dropdown

Tags: wordpress

I've created a twentyfourteen child theme using the One-click child theme plugin. Then I copied the page.php template from the parent theme folder to the file new-template.php in the child folder. I changed the header in new-template.php to

Template Name: New Template

As far as I know that's all I need to do to get "New Template" to show up in the Template dropdown under Page Attributes when you create a new page.  But "New Template" hasn't been added to the dropdown.  Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thank for any help

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987773/template-dropdown-not-showing-up-within-wordpress-administrator-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure You have activated your child theme, if your child theme is already activated  then try a different template name.

Answer (score 10):

Just in Wordpress 4.9 there's this bug: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42573 causing the template files to only be rescanned once every hour.

To fix (until they release a new WP version with this changed), download the patch on that bug ticket and make the changes from the patch to `wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php`.

Hope this saves someone the 2 hours I wasted on this..

Comment: I had the same problem and this actually helped. Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of trouble! :)

Comment: Thanks. spent only 45 minutes on this one hh

Answer (score 6):

For the Wordpress 4.9 bug mentioned above, just update the version of your theme in style.css, e.g. from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3 - even 1.1.2-1 will do. This will force updating templates list.

Comment: Worked for me. Only took me 2 hours of trying to figure out what on Earth was going on. Cheers for the simple suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
<?php /* Template Name: Red Template */ ?>
```

and a copy of page.php in my theme dir called redpage.php

I also had to log out of the admin and then log back in.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and finally did as stol mentioned above. Update the verison of your theme is style.css located in your themes folder. Mine was set to 0.1.3. I updated to 1.1.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1.active your child theme

2.if you optimze your style.css file add again your first comment such as

```
/*
Theme Name: 
Description: 
Author: 
Theme URI: 
Author URI: 
Version: 
Template:     
License: 
License URI: 
Text Domain: 
Tags: 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but this could help someone.

You might have removed the style.css file, it is located in the root of your theme (wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/style.css).

A way of knowing if this is your problem is going inside "Apparence>Themes" and looking for this error: "Error: Stylesheet is missing".

If you do have the error you can copy this and put it inside your style.css

```css
/*
Theme Name: your-theme
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve/
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
Description: The 2012 theme for WordPress is a fully responsive theme that looks great on any device. Features include a front page template with its own widgets, an optional display font, styling for post formats on both index and single views, and an optional no-sidebar page template. Make it yours with a custom menu, header image, and background.
Version: 1.0
Requires at least: 3.5
Requires PHP: 5.2.4
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: blog, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, flexible-header, footer-widgets, full-width-template, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, translation-ready
Text Domain: twentytwelve

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/

/* =Notes
--------------------------------------------------------------
This stylesheet uses rem values with a pixel fallback. The rem
values (and line heights) are calculated using two variables:

$rembase:     14;
$line-height: 24;

---------- Examples

* Use a pixel value with a rem fallback for font-size, padding, margins, etc.
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding: 0.357142857rem 0; (5 / $rembase)

* Set a font-size and then set a line-height based on the font-size
    font-size: 16px
    font-size: 1.142857143rem; (16 / $rembase)
    line-height: 1.5; ($line-height / 16)

---------- Vertical spacing

Vertical spacing between most elements should use 24px or 48px
to maintain vertical rhythm:

.my-new-div {
    margin: 24px 0;
    margin: 1.714285714rem 0; ( 24 / $rembase )
}

---------- Further reading

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem
http://blog.typekit.com/2011/11/09/type-study-sizing-the-legible-letter/


/* =Reset
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```