# In wp-admin not able to set custom page template to any page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on new wordpress setup version 6.1.1, in wp-admin I wants to set Home **Page Template** but I am not getting any option in **Page Attribute** to set my custom page template to any of pages

I am attaching the image for my issue.

Please let me know if there is any other setup I have to do before setting Page Template

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you still have a style.css in your template folder? if its not there, the dropdown for template selection wont show!.. also make sure your template file has the following at the top of the file.. 
/**
* Template Name: TempaltePageName
*/

see answers here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987773/template-dropdown-not-showing-up-within-wordpress-administrator-page

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens when you don't have more than one page template.
If you are building gutenberg blocks theme
Locate/create theme.json file (hopefully you have it). Search "customTemplates" attribute. if you don't find crate some thing like below

```
"customTemplates": [
    {
        "name": "blank",
        "postTypes": [
            "page",
            "post"
        ],
        "title": "Blank"
    },
    {
        "name": "blog-alternative",
        "postTypes": [
            "page"
        ],
        "title": "Blog (Alternative)"
    },
    {
        "name": "404",
        "postTypes": [
            "page"
        ],
        "title": "404"
    }
],
```

If you are building theme based on legacy architecture

Create a page template, you can follow the "twenty twenty-one" theme's directory structure, and then you will be able to access the list of pages.